# How to configure Jboss 7 (v7.1.0) to run as a windows service

Tags: windows, jboss, windows-services, jboss7.x

I need to run Jboss 7.1.0 as a windows service. I have seen some instructions from google but most seem to be for earlier versions of Jboss.

Most examples seem to point to this location for a native library - http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads/jboss-native-2-0-10

What is the native library and what does it do? 
I tried to download the native library and looked at the batch file used for setting up the service. It refers to startup scripts that don't exist in v7.1.0.

Are there any instructions anywhere specifically for v7.1.0 or maybe 7.0.2 as they are almost the same?