# Running JBoss 7.1.1.Final as a windows service

Tags: windows, jboss, windows-services, jboss7.x

What is a right instructions to run JBoss 7 as a windows service?

Configuration:
Windows Server 2008 64 bit,
Java version "1.6.0_26" 64 bit,
JBoss 7.1.1.Final.

I cannot find any official manual of how to perform this.
Thank you.

PS: A similar question has been closed here on stackoverflow - [How to configure Jboss 7 (v7.1.0) to run as a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400406/how-to-configure-jboss-7-v7-1-0-to-run-as-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I've found out that the most relevant sources would be these two links:
 - [Jboss 7.1.1 as Windows service](https://community.jboss.org/message/724488),
 - [Running JBoss AS 7 as a
   Windows service](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RunningJBossAS7AsAWindowsService)

The most strange for me is that there's not any specific native connectors at http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads/jboss-native-2-0-10.html for **JBoss 7**.
So we need to modify **JBoss 5** connector (*service.bat* file specifically) to reflect structural changes of the JBoss version 7.

An updated service.bat is taken from [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/724488) (all changes are in bold there).
The changes are as follows:

1. We should change the service name (Jboss 5 to Jboss 7)
2. Switch all run.bat calls to standalone.bat calls
3. Replace all shutdown calls with new command (as there's not any shutdown.bat anymore! ignoring this might lead to calling windows
   shutdown command instead!)
4. (Optional) Modify the JAVA_OPTS.

PS Consider reading [this](http://canotech.wordpress.com/2012/08/10/running-jboss7-in-service-mode-using-java-service-wrapper/) article as another way to go. However I've not tried it yet.

Comment: You should accept this if it answers your question (even if you've answered it yourself!)

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RunningJBossAS7AsAWindowsService?_sscc=t) looks like a comprehensive guide.

> First of all, grab the appropriate native connectors from
>   http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads/jboss-native-2-0-10 (x86 for
>   32bit host, x64 for 64bit). If you are not sure, use the 32bit version
>   since they will work on 64bit systems also but the reverse is not
>   true. Unzip the archive in the JBoss main folder. Then make some
>   modifications to the service.bat file

(several modifications then listed)

Comment: Thanks Brian. I've expanded your question below.